# Is there an outline version of Concrete Roman Slanted Condensed font?

Tags: fonts

I can't figure out whether any of the packages like `beton`, `concmath`, `ccfonts` or `concrete` have an outline version of the Concrete Roman Slanted Condensed (`ccslc9`) font. [Concmath documentation](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/concmath/concmath.pdf) have a declaration for it on page 5, but I haven't been able to use it (actually I don't know if it's of any use).

---

For the sake of information, I've found a workaround with the bitmap font that is to use

```
\font\ccslc=ccslc9 at 10pt
%% increase resolution of bitmap faces:
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
\pdfpkresolution=8000
```

In the preamble and then

```
{\ccslc Some text}
```

where you need it.

Comment: The T1 encoded Concrete fonts have a Type1 version in CM-Super (they're called `eorm` and `eosl`). But I see no entry for condensed slanted.

Comment: Thank you @egreg. `beton` also provides a slanted font, but not a condensed one. Where have you looked for the 'entry'?

Comment: I looked in `pdftex.map` after looking in `t1ccr.fd` for the TFM file names.